# How can I send a JMS message when content changes in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

So when a piece of content changes (add, edit, or delete) I need to send a message to a JMS server with the document's ID.

How would I do this?

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with? I just went through their documentation and they have plugin support. So you could write a plugin and then send a JMS message during one of their callbacks.

Comment: I find their documentation to be just shy of useless unless someone points me to the exact page that demonstrates what I need. All too often I've seen "we support X" with no mention on how to actually do X.

Comment: Sounds like you're probably looking at the wrong site then. For details on how to do things, you'll want [docs.alfresco.com](http://docs.alfresco.com) and [wiki.alfresco.com](http://wiki.alfresco.com) - www.alfresco.com tells you what is supported while those two tell you how to use and extend it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A custom behaviour should do the trick. Have a look at
[Email Notifications on Calendar Events in Alfresco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906592/email-notifications-on-calendar-events-in-alfresco/9907448) for an `onCreateNode` example. Update and removal works in a similiar fashion.

Assumimg JNDI is set up correctly, lookup the JMS queue/topic and create/send the message.